# R change value based on text in other column

Tags: r, replace, statistics, tidyverse

Here i am again. I have a possible answer for my other post.

```
library(tidyr)

age <- c("18-30","18-30","31-45", 60)
YesNo1 <- c("Yes", NA,NA,NA)
Height1 <- c(250,NA,NA,NA)
YesNo2 <- c(NA,"NO",NA,NA)
Height2 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA)
YesNo3 <- c(NA,NA,"Yes", NA)
Height3 <- c(NA,NA,320,NA)
YesNo4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,"yes")
Height4 <- c(NA,NA,NA, 290)

Test <- data.frame(age, YesNo1, Height1, YesNo2, Height2, 
                   YesNo3, Height3, YesNo4,Height4)
#inspect the data
Test

# reduce the columns 

mi <- pivot_longer(Test, c(YesNo1, YesNo2, YesNo3, YesNo4), 
                         names_to = "decision", values_to = "yes/no")

mi1 <- pivot_longer(mi, c(Height1, Height2, Height3, Height4), 
                    names_to = "alimony", values_to = "height")

#drop the NA rows
mi2 <- mi1 %>% drop_na('yes/no')
```

This is a simplified version of my dataset. the real one contains 4100 rows. As you can see in the end, i get 4 time the same row, but the respondents answered only one question so the other 3 are unneccessary. I was thinking it could help to fill in the value 0 in column Height 2 when No was answered in YesNo2. Then i can justdelete the empty rows afterwards.
I tried this:

```
df$Height2(df$YesNo2 == "No") <- 0
```

However, i get an error. anyone an idea how i can solve this or fix it another way?

Comment: Replace `(` with `[`: `df$Height2[df$YesNo2 == "No"]  <- 0` should work.

Comment: I tried and i get this error Error in `*tmp*`$Height2 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable any idea what it means and how to fix?

Comment: Your data frame is not actually called `df` so you are trying to subset the function `df()`. Try replacing `df` with the name of your data frame, `mi1`.